# Wilcox.test in R - not enough x observations

Tags: r, statistics

I'm new to R and trying to perform a wilcox.test on water quality data. My data is long form and I've subset the data to create "preWWTF" and "postWWTF" to group data before or after an upstream wastewater treatment facility upgrade. The code I'm using is:

```
wilcox.test(x=preWWTF$Result [preWWTF$Loc_Analyte=="BarkTop_DP"],
        y=postWWTF$Result [postWWTF$Loc_Analyte=="BarkTop_DP"],
        paired = FALSE)
```

I get the error "not enough (finite) 'x' observations". There are no NA or blank values. However, preWWTF has fewer observations than postWWTF. Is there some code language I can use to 'truncate' the post WWTF data so there are the same number of observations pre vs. post? I assume that is what is causing the issue. Thanks.

Comment: This problem is not reproducible, so we will all just be guessing. Did you check to make sure that both of your columns are numeric (and not just numbers encoded as characters or factors)?

Comment: I think the `<-` is an error that is doing wierd things you do not intend. If you want to change what `preWWTF$Loc_anlayte` is do it on a different line so you can inspect what is going into your function.

Comment: Try using `[preWWTF$Loc_Analyte == "BarkTop_DP"]`

Comment: A better practice is to create your inputs in lines above the function call, then you can check they are what you think they are before calling the function.

Comment: Seth and Dave2e - Using == instead of <- did help, however I still get the error with all other parameters. Since pre-data has 36 variables and post-data has 50 variables, is there a way to truncate the post-data in R? Odd that this seems to be an issue given that the samples are not paired.

Comment: With `paired = FALSE` you should be ok having the length of the two vectors being different. Convince yourself by running something like `wilcox.test(1:10,12:50,paired =F)` , there is something else wrong with your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just going to write something here that may help debug your problem.

assign your data to a new object named x

```
x=preWWTF$Result [preWWTF$Loc_Analyte=="BarkTop_DP"]
```

inspect that x

```
summary(x)
View(x)
```

compare what you see here to what you see in the source data.frame preWWTF, make sure you have extracted the values you expect.

assign your y to an object

```
y= postWWTF$Result [postWWTF$Loc_Analyte=="BarkTop_DP"]
```

inspect y

```
summary(y)
View(y)
```

If there is anything that you don't understand in those summaries post back here. So long as everything is a number and nothing is NA or INF then proceed to run your model.

```
wilcox.test(x, y,
         paired = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! This found that there were empty rows of data (essentially NAs) that I couldn't see. Thanks for taking the time to help me.